# Error C2039: 'Collections': is not a member of 'Windows::Foundation'

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime

Well this is embarassing, and I know it's going to show up as lack of research effort.

I am a very skilled C# programmer with plenty of experience in the field, but I want to learn C++ since it opens up some very interesting opportunities within (for instance) DirectX. For a long time I've used SharpDX to simulate the same, but now I want to learn the real deal.

So I decided to create a Windows Store DLL library in C++. At first glance, C++ seems a lot different, but after some research, I learned the structure of the `.h` and `.cpp` files. It now seems more manageable to me.

However, I am having issues with references.

I want to make a class inherit from a `Control` (in XAML). I figured I had to import the proper libraries, and that referencing system libraries in C++ must be done through the code files themselves (perhaps because of the linking process?).

**Graph.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <wrl.h>

#include <windows.foundation.h>
#include <windows.foundation.collections.h>

#include <windows.ui.h>
#include <windows.ui.xaml.h>
#include <windows.ui.xaml.controls.h>

#include "pch.h"

namespace Techmatic_FunctionGraph
{
    public ref class Graph sealed : public Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Control
    {
    public:
        Graph();
    }
}
```

**Graph.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Graph.h"

#include <windows.foundation.h>
#include <windows.foundation.collections.h>

#include <windows.ui.h>
#include <windows.ui.xaml.h>
#include <windows.ui.xaml.controls.h>

using namespace Techmatic_FunctionGraph;

using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Documents;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;

using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging;

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

Techmatic_FunctionGraph::Graph()
{
}
```

However, I am getting an error that says that `using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;` isn't a proper namespace or class name.

As you may see I am pretty much just fumbling in blindness. I tried Googling "C++ reference Windows::Foundation::Collections" and other queries without luck.

Can anyone help me understand what I am missing here to move on, or guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you creating a Windows Store App using C++/CX? You may not require  to `#include` .h files.

Comment: Yes, I am. Now things got worse with even more errors.

Comment: Could you share your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project settings, make sure you set "Consume Windows Runtime Extension" to "Yes (/ZW)" and I think that's all you'll need.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you try this way?

```
#include <collection.h>
```

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Windows/Apps/hh441496.aspx)